# How to refactor two overloads into one

Tags: c#, generics, refactoring

I stumbled upon two methods overload with exactly the same body and I would like to refactor it to just a single one.

```
    private static bool Compare<T>(T obj1, T obj2, out int test) where T : IComparable<T>
    {}

    private static bool Compare(IComparable obj1, IComparable obj2, out int test)
    {}
```

The signatures signify almost the same thing with the only difference being generics. Is there a way to merge them?

Comment: Have you tried just deleting one and seeing what breaks?

Comment: Without seeing the "idenitcal code" it´s impossible to guess how to refactor this. But I suppose you can try to cast the objects used in the non-generic version to the generic type-argument and call that one, e.g. `Compare((MyType) obj1, (MyType) obj1, out test)`.

Comment: I am going out on a limb here, but you could probably refactor out most of the code into a 3rd private method, and keep only the interface-specific `IComparable<T>.CompareTo` and `IComparable.CompareTo` calls in your different Compare<T> and Compare methods...

Comment: @elgonzo Sound advice. I did just that and while not achieving exactly what I wanted, there is at least no duplicate code.

Comment: I don't imagine the amount of code in those methods amount to a lot anyway, seeing as one of them is generic and you're saying they have the same body. Since we've already established that the two interfaces are not compatible, does it really matter if you keep both methods?

Comment: It was more of an exercise to me. Had the code in those bodies been a 100 loc (nothing out of ordinary within the company) then it would be appropriate to refactor without a question.

Answer (score 5):

Comments are correct in so far that both methods are not the same because `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` are different interfaces.

But its still instructing to be aware that, given the following scenario:

```
private static bool Compare<T>(
   T obj1, 
   T obj2, 
   out int test) where T : IComparable { }

private static bool Compare(
    IComparable obj1, 
    IComparable obj2, 
    out int test) { }
```

If you refactor that code to one single overload you would be performing a breaking change. Those two overloads are most definitely *not* the same.

In the generic overload, `obj1` and `obj2` must be the *same compile time type* (*). In the second overload, `obj1` and `obj2` can be *different types* as long as they implement `IComparable`.

```
 Compare(1, 1, out test); //resolves to generic
 Compare(1, "s", out test); //resolves to non generic
```

(*) Not strictly true, implicit conversions come into play here.

Answer (score 0):

As @elgonzo advised I got rid of the duplicate body by refactoring it out to a 3rd method.

```
    static bool CompareT<T>(T obj1, T obj2, out int test) where T : IComparable<T> =>
        Compare(obj1, obj2, () => obj1.CompareTo(obj2), out test);

    static bool Compare(IComparable obj1, IComparable obj2, out int test) =>
        Compare(obj1, obj2, () => obj1.CompareTo(obj2), out test);

    static bool Compare(object obj1, object obj2, Func<int> f, out int test)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2))
        {
            test = 0;
            return true;
        }

        if (obj1 == null)
        {
            test = 1;
            return false;
        }

        test = f();

        if (test == 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

I include the body here just for reference as to see the use of the *f* argument. In the place of its call in the original methods was the *CompareTo* call.
Thanks goes to all commenters for clarifying why the reduction to a single signature isn't viable.